# How to save an array of object in mongo db using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Giving the following snippets of object below:

```
var s;
var tab = [];
var myarray= [];
for(var i=0;i<=tab.length-1;i++){
              s= "{\"id\":\"" + tab[i][0] + "\",\"ts\":\"" + tab[i][1] + "\",\"lat\":\"" + tab[i][2] + "\",\"lon\":\""+tab[i][3]+"\"}";
                myarray.push(s);
            }

myarray = [ '{"id":"id1","ts":"ts1","lat":"lat1","lon":"lon1"}',
  '{"id":"id2","ts":"ts2","lat":"lat2","lon":"lon2"}',
  '{"id":"id3","ts":"ts3","lat":"lat3","lon":"lon3"}' ]
```

I want to save it in mongo database by using mongoose, this is my code:

```
for(var obj in myarray){
       var doc = new MyCollection(myarray[obj])
        doc.save()
                  .catch((err=>{console.log(error.message);}))
            }
```

But I get this error when executing the code:

```
TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '_id' in {"id":"id1","ts":"ts1","lat":"lat1","lon":"lon1"}
```

I don't find the source of the error. Can you help me please?

Comment: That's not an object, that's a "string". See the quotes `'` around it. Seems like you have a parser problem somewhere. Or something doing a `.toString()` where it should not be.

Comment: And if it were an `Object` then you would just be doing `for (var obj in myarray) { var doc = new MyCollection(obj); .....` since its the actual `Object` and not the "keyname" or "index" that you are getting from the `for`

Comment: Thx! I just parsed to JSON each object of my array then i got single quotes disappeared

Comment: That is expected. The real thing you should be looking at is how they got there in the first place. Inserting a `JSON.parse` may be a quick fix, but it's going to confuse anyone reading the code, wondering why the line is put in there. So you "should" track down the source of how these came to be in strings in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in myarray you have enclosed object using single quotes.remove it and try. your myarray should be like this.

```
myarray: [ {"id":"id1","ts":"ts1","lat":"lat1","lon":"lon1"}',
  '{"id":"id2","ts":"ts2","lat":"lat2","lon":"lon2"}',
  '{"id":"id3","ts":"ts3","lat":"lat3","lon":"lon3"} ];

for(var obj in myarray){
       var doc = new MyCollection(myarray[obj])
        sigfoxData.save()
                  .catch((err=>{console.log(error.message);}))
            }
```

Comment: Thx! I just parsed to JSON each object of my array then i got single quotes disappeared

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
 var myarray = [ {"id":"id1","ts":"ts1","lat":"lat1","lon":"lon1"}',
        '{"id":"id2","ts":"ts2","lat":"lat2","lon":"lon2"}',
        '{"id":"id3","ts":"ts3","lat":"lat3","lon":"lon3"} ];

    Model.create(myarray, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            response.send({error: true, message: err});
        } else {
            response.send({success: true});
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I got solution by doing this:

```
for(var i=0;i<=tab.length-1;i++){
              s= "{\"id\":\"" + tab[i][0] + "\",\"ts\":\"" + tab[i][1] + "\",\"lat\":\"" + tab[i][2] + "\",\"lon\":\""+tab[i][3]+"\"}";
                myarray.push(JSON.parse(s));
            }
```

So i just parsed the s string!